# Is there some mechanism to be notified when a question can be deleted?

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956094/this-is-a-test-title-and-this-is-cool-closed). I don't vote to delete many questions, but this one more than obviously exceeds the criteria that should be met for deletion.

The problem is, I'll likely forget to vote to delete it. While I'm sure that this question will be obliterated in 48 hours, others that don't meet the criteria so obviously might not be. As I go through the site, I make mental notes of questions that were closed that I really  feel should be deleted after making sure they can't just be merged, but I often forget about them.

Is there some mechanism that will tell me when a question has been closed for 48 hours? I'm trying to make a concerted effort to help keep things clean, but I'd like to do so without consuming post-it notes :)

Maybe something like "Flag for follow up" , which reminds me of the question two days later, similar to how favorites work? Sometimes this is a non-issue, if i can spend a few solid hours to go through the lists. Often, I don't have that much time.

Comment: only 2 more flags needed to be deleted

Comment: don't delete it. It is a good question ! Can somebody explain why it is a duplicate ? The "original" question is not a question because it doesn't have any interrogation character and because the Notification feature is not present ! Is the eraser a robot that doens't understand the difference between this question and another ?